# Кнопки не отображаются в Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Новичок в C#. Добавил через конструктор две кнопки, поменял им текст, но при запуске программы открывается пустое окно. Почему они не отображаются?

До этого делал кнопки через код и всё было в порядке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Файл Form1.cs*

```
namespace new_project_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

```
*Файл Form1.Designer.cs* 

namespace new_project_1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 52);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Создайте матрицу 1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 81);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Создайте матрицу 2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "laba_1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;
    }
}
```

Comment: В файле Form1.Designer.cs вроде бы всё есть, но Form1.cs пустой. Это критично? Какая между ними разница?

P.S. Разницу примерно понимаю - в .cs пишем код, в Designer "рисуем" компоненты

Comment: В конструкторе формы нужно вызвать метод `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, как-то не заметил, что он пропал

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оформите свой комментарий с правильным решением как ответ, это может кому-то понадобиться еще)